# PHP Create Zip on the fly with password

Tags: php, zip, password-protection, on-the-fly

Try to make Zip file with password on the fly

```
<?php
$fileRequest = 'cooking-book';

// Prepare File
$file = tempnam("tmp", "zip");
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($file, ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

// Stuff with content
$getFile = file_get_contents('http://otherserver.com/getfile.php?sq='.$fileRequest);
$zip->addFromString('cooking-book.txt', $getFile);

// Close and send to users
$zip->close();
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fileRequest.'.zip"');
readfile($file);
unlink($file);
?>
```

Now it's work fine (download file from other server to memory, zip it, and send it to user).

How to set password on zip? (exec() shell_exec() can't use) And where in the code it must be?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

now is the future, and now you can it do: (PHP7.x feature)

ZipArchive::setEncryptionName — Set the encryption method of an entry defined by its name
http://php.net/manual/de/ziparchive.setencryptionname.php

```
<?php
$fileRequest = 'cooking-book';
$passwort = 'PW';

// Prepare File
$file = tempnam("tmp", "zip");
$zip = new ZipArchive();

if ($zip->open($file, ZipArchive::OVERWRITE) === TRUE) {
    // Stuff with content
    $getFile = file_get_contents('http://otherserver.com/getfile.php?sq='.$fileRequest);
    $zip->addFromString('cooking-book.txt', $getFile);
    $zip->setEncryptionName('cooking-book.txt', ZipArchive::EM_AES_256, $passwort);
    // Close and send to users
    $zip->close();
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fileRequest.'.zip"');
    readfile($file);
    unlink($file);
} else {
    echo "Error ;)";
}
?>
```

Comment: Please note that this will work only if php is built against libzip ≥ 1.2.0. https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.setencryptionname.php

Answer (score -5):

If you are using PHP 5.6, you can use [ZipArchive::setPassword](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.setpassword.php) to add a password to the currently active archive.

You would use it like this:

```
$zip->setPassword("YourPasswordHere");
```

I'd add it before `$zip->close();`

Comment: Unfortunately my PHP version isn't 5.6, and I can't upgrde it on my hosting. Other ways?

Comment: this still does not work in current PHP versions, because setPassword is only for decompression! see note from the manual:
This function only sets the password to be used to decompress the archive; it does not turn a non-password-protected ZipArchive into a password-protected ZipArchive.  - http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.setpassword.php